# MySQL fetching number of rows found (not necessarily affected) during last update query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I would like to identify UPDATE queries that didn't update anything because there was no matching row to update (and not because that row contained the exact same values)

AFAIK the rowCounts will return how many affected rows during last query, and I'd like to get how many matching rows were found. I've noticed the MySQL workbench displays that, so I"m guessing there's a way but couldn't find it.

I'm using PDO.

Comment: If query didn't update anything then `rowCount()` returns 0, isn't it?

Comment: I suppose you are using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. Is this right ?

Comment: @u_mulder AFAIK it doesn't update either if the row stayed the same, or it didn't exist in the first place. I'm trying to differ between the two cases.

Comment: @sand I'm actually not, just a plain old UPDATE, but obviously open to that.

Answer (score 1):

This information is [not available in PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#affected).

Although native mysql applications can get such information from the driver, (see [mysqli_info()](http://php.net/mysqli_info)), in PDO such information is not available.

All you can do is to set `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS` as a connection option, but it's far from being reliable as in such a case you won't get the number of rows actually updated.

So to get your number I would simply run a SELECT query with the same condition.

Comment: Can you elaborate why PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS is not reliable?

Comment: I thought I wrote it in the same sentence

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) option when you connect to MySQL server via PDO to get the number of records matched returned rather than the number of records changed by an update statement:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=yourdb;host=yourhosthost', 'username', 'psw', array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => true
));
```